# Blender + Google Sketchup 7

Tags: conversion, python, perl, blender, sketchup

I have been trying to import a model from Google Sketchup 7 into Blender 2.49.

I have read countless tutorials on how to export it using the Sketchup program into various formats, but these are not the most viable solution to me because I run a pure 64-bit Linux system (Wine is 64-bit only) and Sketchup isn't available for 64-bit Windows (or 64-bit Linux for that matter). Honestly, I'd much rather find a standalone conversion tool.

I've done countless searches for a viable solution to this problem, and the best near miss I have come up with is using no-longer-maintained [Collada plugin for Blender](http://colladablender.illusoft.com/cms/), but, while this is a valid Blender script, it seems to have suffered some software rot, as the models it imports do not have any size and are stuck waaay above the origin.

I have also tried using [this Blender import script](http://jmsoler.free.fr/didacticiel/blender/tutor/py_import_kml-kmz_en.htm) to import the models. The problem with this solution is that the script seems to have been written for older versions of both Blender and Google Sketchup—Sketchup 3 is the latest it supports.

I have also tried finding many other routes of finding a converter to a go-between format that is a standard model format (md2, md3, md5, ase, obj, wml or 3ds) which Blender can read.

My question is, has anyone come across, or has written a standalone program that will convert, preferably in a higher-level language like Perl or Python, or even Ruby, either Google Sketchup 7 (.skp) or Collada v1.4.1 (.dae) to a format Blender can read?

If not, I'll write one, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if it's out there already.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to import simple Sketchup models in Blender 2.49 using the Collada 1.4.1 importer.
The xml file creates some unnecessary nodes that end up as parent/parented empty objects in Blender.

[Ira Krakow's KMZ Import tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioUzS9b1EkE) shows some nice techniques, but mainly there's still plenty of cleaning up to do.

With a custom importer, this could be avoided.

I haven't used Ruby before, but it looks somewhat similar to Python. Maybe this [Direct X exporter](http://www.scriptspot.com/files/u6408/ZbylsXExporter.rb) script can be a good starting point for your exporter.